# MySQL get a summary of data based on part of a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of user information, from which I want to get a report listing the most common domains. I know that I need to use count and group by, but I'm not sure how to group by only part of a string, from the '@' symbol on. Any advice?

```
id  email                name          etc..
---------------------------------------------
1   username@domain.com  User Userson  blah
```

Comment: The below answers will work, but will run very very slow. If you want to run this query often, create an extra column called domain, put an index on that field and fill it with `UPDATE table1 SET domain = substring_index(email,'@',-1)` then you can run this query near instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) might be useful here:

```
select 
  substring_index(email,'@',-1) as domain
  ,count(*) as userCount 
from your_table
group by domain 
order by usercount desc;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. And was just a bit faster than the other option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, using [`LOCATE()` and `SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(email FROM LOCATE('@', email)) AS domain
  COUNT(*) AS numusers
FROM tbl
GROUP BY domain
ORDER BY numusers DESC
```

The above will list domains as `@example.com`.  To strip off the `@` use instead:

```
SUBSTRING(email FROM LOCATE('@', email)+1) AS domain
```

Comment: You can use an alias in the group by clause :-)

Comment: @Johan Tested and you are correct :) I've been working with SQL Server all week, where that isn't allowed